# Java Calendar: Getting Difference Between Two Dates/Times - Off by One

Tags: java, date, calendar, datediff

I have seen many questions and answers on this topic, but none addressed my particular problem.  I extended the java Calendar class (standard--no third party libraries), and needed to find the difference in **days** between two arbitrary dates.

Method:

1. Change the time of both dates to midnight.
2. Convert the dates to milliseconds.
3. Find the difference between the two dates.
4. Divide the result by the number of milliseconds in a day (24 * 60 *
   60 * 1000).
5. The result should be the difference in days.

And it sometimes is, and it sometimes isn't.  Even tests on the same date can be off by one. What's going on?

Comment: On a side note, are you sure it was a good idea to *extend* `Calendar` as opposed to producing a helper library that operates on `Calendar` instances?

Comment: One problem is that you assume there are 86400000ms in a day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by other users, you need to also set the millisecond value of the calendars to zero to compare only the dates. This can be achieved with the following code snippet:

```
someCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
```

Also, note that timezone changes (e.g. moving from winter time to summer time) may mean there is more or less than 86,400,000 ms in a day.

Comment: The elegant solution!  I should have read the docs more thoroughly (like we all have time!).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 14):

The [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) Library has very good support for such problems:

```
LocalDate d1 = new LocalDate(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
LocalDate d2 = new LocalDate(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());
int days = Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).getDays();
```

UPDATE (feedback from @basil-bourque):

As of Java 8 the new time library `java.time` has been introduced, now a similar option without external dependencies is available:

```
int days = Duration.between(calendar1.toInstant(), calendar2.toInstant()).toDays();
```

Comment: That's really a good solution, I think it's wise to consider some outside library, particularly such a small and nice one like JodaTime. Works perfect and gives exactly what you want.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks, added the version using `java.time` from JRE 8 libraries

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for this. That class purposely loses all offset and time zone information. So you will be working with generic 24-hour days and ignoring the anomalies represented in time zones such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42545700/642706) for details.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  It says .toInstant() does not exist!  What Calendar does it have to be exactly?

Comment: @doctorram `java.util.Calendar.toInstant()` is available from Java 8 runtime libs

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( then , now )
```

## Naïve calculations

You assume in your code that every day is exactly twenty four hours long. Not true. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) mean that days may vary such as 23 hours long, 25 hours, or other numbers. The very meaning of a time zone is to track a history of these anomalies.

Also, you assume the day starts at midnight. Not true. Because of anomalies, some days start at other time-of-day such as `01:00`.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Time zone

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## Do not extend java.time

Do not extend (subclass) the java.time classes (they are marked `final`).

And do not generalize to their interfaces for your business logic; stick to the concrete classes of this framework. While generalizing makes sense in other frameworks such as [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework), not so in java.time.

## Using java.time

This work is *much* easier with the java.time classes.

[`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) represents a moment on the timeline with an assigned tim zone (`ZoneId`).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );

// of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone)
ZonedDateTime then = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56 , 123456789 , z );

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

The [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum can calculate elapsed time between a pair of moments.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( then , now );
```

See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Vt2qaI).

> then.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34:56.123456789-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> now.toString(): 2017-03-01T21:26:04.884-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> days: 37

## Converting legacy instances to java.time

If you are given [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) objects, convert to java.time using new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

If you know a `Calendar` instance is actually a `GregorianCalendar`, cast it.

```
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = (GregorianCalendar) myCal ;
```

## Half-Open

The java.time classes define spans of time by the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I have written a much more simpler way to tackle this problem, even i faced the same problem of having one day extra for some dates.

This is my approach currently,

```
    public long getDays(long currentTime, long endDateTime) {

    Calendar endDateCalendar;
    Calendar currentDayCalendar;


    //expiration day
    endDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    endDateCalendar.setTimeInMillis(endDateTime);
    endDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    endDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

    //current day
    currentDayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    currentDayCalendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
    currentDayCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    currentDayCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    currentDayCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

    long remainingDays = Math.round((float) (endDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentDayCalendar.getTimeInMillis()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    return remainingDays;
}
```

previously I was using this piece of line, rest is same :-

```
long remainingDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
            Math.abs(expiryCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentDayCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```

But seems to be not working for me.

Comment: I did this: double remainingDays = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - calNow.getTimeInMillis()) / (24.0 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Answer (score 3):

You recognized the issue in step one by setting the time to midnight: that made sure that all the hours, minutes, and seconds were at zero.  But you didn't go far enough!  You also have to make sure that the **milliseconds** are zeroed out, too.

Here's some code to do exactly that.

```
protected long truncate_to_seconds (long date_in_millis) {
    long l = date_in_millis / 1000L;
    l *= 1000L;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: No need for the truncate method, he can just zero the milliseconds on the `Calendar` instances with `set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)`.

Comment: @DuncanJones Even BETTER!  Didn't see that aspect of the Calendar library, thanks!!

Comment: @DuncanJones: please add this as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe you need to truncate the time part** from the date before computing the difference as below:

```
   DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
   String truncatedDateString1 = formatter.format(date1);
   Date truncatedDate1 = formatter.parse(truncatedDateString1);

   String truncatedDateString2 = formatter.format(date2);
   Date truncatedDate2 = formatter.parse(truncatedDateString2);

   long timeDifference = truncatedDate2.getTime()- truncatedDate1.getTime();

   int daysInBetween = timeDifference / (24*60*60*1000);
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have my function as purpose at your request. I was using calendar, i set all the time part to 0 before compare.

```
    int countDays(Date dateBegin, Date dateEnd) {
    if (dateBegin == null || dateEnd == null)
        return 0;
    Calendar from = asCalendar(dateBegin); // asCalendar() Initialise a Calendar from a Date
    Calendar to = asCalendar(dateEnd);
    // Set the time part to 0
    from.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    from.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    from.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    from.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    to.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    to.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    to.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    to.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    int nbJours = 0;
    for (Calendar c = from ; c.before(to) ; c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1))
    {
        nbJours++;
    }
    for (Calendar c = from ; c.after(to) ; c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1))
    {
        nbJours--;
    }
    return nbJours;
    }
```