# I can't do math with calendar method in Java, but got the "java: bad operand types for binary operator '-'" error

Tags: java, date, math, calendar

I'm trying to make a code that tells me how many days left for me to go college, but I am not able to do it with the current date. I can easily make it by setting a date, but I want the current date, so I have to use the calendar method, but can't do math using it.
My code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date start = sdf.parse("10/06/2022");
    System.out.println(start - calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Calendar: Getting Difference Between Two Dates/Times - Off by One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198609/java-calendar-getting-difference-between-two-dates-times-off-by-one)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter` and`ChronoUnit.DAYS`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate days between two Dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8)

Comment: No one should use the JDK 1.0 vintage Calendar class.  Prefer the classes in java.util.time package.

Comment: @duffymo JDK 1.1 to be precise. Still more than 25 years old, and still replaced by java.time 8 years ago this month. You are 100 % correct, that class is not to be used (repeating myself).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) , 
    LocalDate.parse( "10/06/2022" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) 
)
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`/`Calendar`.

Also, you are attempting to use a date-time class representing a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC (offset of zero) to hold a date-only value. Square peg, round hole.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate graduationDate = LocalDate.parse( "10/06/2022" , f ) ;
```

Determine today's date. That requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault()
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time using [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( today , graduationDate ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JO7Qgc).

```
graduationDate: 2022-06-10
today: 2022-03-05
days: 97
```

Tip: Learn about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for exchanging date-time values as text.

Comment: +1. And, just a purely stylistic comment for the OP, I would statically import `ChronoUnit.DAYS` so that the code simply read as `DAYS.between` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   
    Calendar collegeDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    collegeDate.set(Calendar.DATE,10);
    collegeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    collegeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2022);
    System.out.println(Duration.between(calendar.toInstant(), collegeDate.toInstant()).toDays());
```

Comment: If you know to use Duration and toInstant(), why are you using Calendar? Just stick with proper, modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date start = sdf.parse("10/06/2022");

        long dif = Math.abs(calendar.getTimeInMillis() - start.getTime());
        long result = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(dif, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason in 2022 to be using Calendar, Date, or SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @DavidConrad The question does not have a detailed description. Perhaps the author wants to use this code in his android application. If so, then this is the best solution, because for example the Duration class requires a minimum of android version 8 to work.

Comment: @Leonid Not so. java.time is available for lower Android versions through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) (also there is no mention of Android in the question, so an answer assuming it’s for Android is either inappropriate or should at least state clearly that the answer is for lower version Android only). As this answer stands, it is likely to lead more users astray than on a good track.

Comment: The answer is also wrong. It assumes there are 24 hours in a day. This is not always the case.

Comment: @DavidConrad as I said, it's a countdown to my college start, meaning I'm learning the basics of java :)

Comment: @AfonsoBritto Neither `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` nor `Date` belongs to the basics of Java. They belong to the outdated and troublesome Java classes that everyone should avoid and learners even more so.

Comment: @AfonsoBritto [Sun Microsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems), [Oracle Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation), and the [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) community all gave up on those terrible legacy date-time classes when they unanimously adopted [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).